# How to fix a Micro SD card inside a USB 2.0 adapter that is not working?

Tags: windows-7, usb, sd-card

I have a Micro SD card inside a USB 2.0 adapter that is not working. 
I have tried a few different methods to fix my flash drive with no results.
The micro SD card is 32 GB inserted into a USB 2.0 adapter.

- When I plug the drive into a port, Windows 7 makes a sound, and I am prompted to format the drive. I failed after a number attempts to format the drive. I tried all the ports on three different computers (same results).
- Next, I uninstalled the USB driver and reinstalled the flash drive **FAILED**
- I opened CMD, entered `diskpart` > `select disk 1` > `clean`
  and I followed more steps that I found online but still **FAILED**
- I changed the LETTER of the drive, then continued the step above **FAILED**
- I tried to insert the drive into my Xbox 360 to try to format it **FAILED**
- I tried four different recovery programs **FAILED**
- I tried to format each sector (it took 3 hours) **FAILED**
- I removed the card from the adapter and placed it into an SD card, then inserted it into my laptop **FAILED**
- I tired using a micro USB adapter to connect to my cell phone to erase ALL on the drive **FAILED**
- I tried to use ERASER software to delete all on the drive **FAILED**

The drive was working fine two days ago. It was used to store video games and add-ons on my Xbox 360 console. Two days ago, I went to play a game on the drive, but it wasn't there. In fact, the console read the drive was almost full; however, the contents was empty.

I would like to delete, erase or reset the drive so I can use it again. 
I don't need to recover its contents;
I can always re-download the games and stuff.

What can I do?

Comment: Yes, the solution is very simple. Open your trash can, insert the SD card, then close it. After that, buy a storage medium that is actually suitable for use with an XBox.

Comment: SD cards fail. Based on the evidence you've provided, I would guess that your SD card has failed. As Daniel notes: when considering future storage options for your Xbox, I strongly advise you look at devices besides an SD card. They are simply not the best for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check your USB adapter for a write protect switch however you say putting just the microSD in your phone still fails so I do not see that being the cause. The most likely culprit is the flash memory is worn out and will not function anymore, however I have had success in the past by using ChkFlsh https://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/chkflsh_en to recover both an SD card and a USB flash drive that would fail to format.

1. Download and right click **run-as-administrator** ChkFlsh from the link above (the download button is the small text above the picture of the program).
2. Click "As physical device (NT-based systems only)", select your drive from the dropdown list, then scroll down slightly and select "Low level initialization."
3. **VERIFY YOU SELECTED THE CORRECT DRIVE!** This tool can and will wipe whatever device you point it at.
4. Click Start. Click Yes on any warning that comes up (there's a couple different ones depending on what it sees on the drive.)
5. Next a window titled "Partitions" will open up, select partition 0 and click New, on that window that pops up just click OK. (Even if it selects a filesystem you don't like, just use Windows later to reformat it to what you want.)
6. Click Yes to write all changes to disk and when asked replug the device *without* unmounting/safely removing it.

If, and that's a big if, your microSD card is repairable this will have done it and you should have a formatted empty microSD card. If it still doesn't work it can function as a table drink coaster for a tiny mouse family, or just toss it in the trash.

Comment: I followed the steps with the results of 72 plus 'device write errors'  Anyone want a tiny coaster? LoL thanks guys but no good results. I'll buy a new one